# Puppet. Firewall module syntax

Tags: puppet

What mean "->" in puppetlabs examples on [this](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/firewall) page

[image]

Comment: What page is that from? I don't see `firewall` in the type reference.

Comment: @jordanm It is in the README tab for file `my_fw/manifests/pre.pp`. Looks like some puppet specific configuration syntax to me and not ruby (but I have never done anything useful with that).

Comment: I thought that this syntax is used to specify the order, but on a server anywhere else I can not use it.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet uses its own DSL to declare the state a system should be in, see ["The Puppet Language"](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_summary.html).

On "ordering", the reference states

> Puppet’s language is mostly declarative: Rather than listing a series of steps to carry out, a Puppet manifest describes a desired final state.
>
> The resources in a manifest can be freely ordered — they will not be applied to the system in the order they are written. This is because Puppet assumes most resources aren’t related to each other. If one resource depends on another, [you must say so explicitly](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html). (If you want a short section of code to get applied in the order written, you can [use chaining arrows](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#chaining-arrows).)

Indeed, what you highlighted in the screenshot is a **chaining arrow** that tells Puppet to do this before that.  You mention that you cannot use it anywhere else -- have you got an example that doesn't work for you and where the linked docs don't help?